# Don't discard analysis cache when --action_env changes

Tags: bazel

I have an `--action_env` variable I'm passing into Bazel sometimes, but each time I remove it or add it back, it discards the analysis cache, which triggers a re-analysis that takes several minutes because I'm working in a large repo. Is there a way to prevent this? I'm already using `--trim_test_configuration`

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

Not really. You can think of the set of environment variables as a file that **almost** every Bazel action depends on. As a simple example let's say you have a build file that looks something like this;

```
genrule(
  name = "foo_header",
  cmd = "echo #define FOO $FOO_FROM_ENV > foo.h",
  outs = ["foo.h"],
)

cc_library(
  name = "my_library_that_everything_depends_on",
  hdrs = [":foo_header"],
)
```

In this simple case it's not hard to see that if you change `--action_env=FOO_FROM_ENV=7` to another value that everything that depends on `foo.h` now has to be completely rebuilt and analysed. So while frustrating it's probably a good thing that Bazel does this otherwise you'd end up with an inconsistent build.

## Partial workarounds

1. Remove usage of `use_default_shell_env` from your [rules/actions](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/actions.html#run) (this is far from trivial as most of the standard rules do this)
2. Use a [centralised cache](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/remote-caching.html) to prevent Bazel from deleting the artifact cache. e.g. I add these to ~/.bazelrc as then it shares the action/repository cache between all my projects. This only helps if you are switching between env variables on a regular basis rather than using new env values each time. Also, be careful with this as Bazel doesn't presently do any garbage collection so the cache directories can end up very large.

```rc
# ~/.bazelrc
common --disk_cache=~/.cache/shared_bazel_action_cache
common --repository_cache=~/.cache/shared_bazel_repository_cache
```

3. Add `--incompatible_strict_action_env` to your project bazelrc, this will prevent changes in your user shell triggering Bazel to discard the analysis cache.